# Moderator Pro Tem Announcement

Tags: discussion, moderators, public-beta

As we enter the second week of your public beta, we desperately need members from this site whose focus is to engage the community, both in community-building issues and site management. That's why we select a few members from each community to act as temporary, provisional Moderators. You can read about the program here: [**Moderators Pro Tempore**](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/moderator-pro-tempore/).

I am pleased to announce that these members have stepped up and generously volunteered their time to help us assure that each community’s issues are properly addressed:

[image] [image] [image] [image]

We want to make this site a huge success, and these members are great examples of exactly the type of people we need to make this site succeed. Please welcome them for the hard work and time they contribute.

#### Did I overlook anyone?

Almost certainly. There are members who are actively involved and very deserving of recognition. My failure to account for everyone this early on is in *no way* a slight against them. Ideally, Moderators are elected by the community and that's why **you'll have your elections in several weeks.**

Most of all, be respectful and understanding of the Moderators Pro Tem. Members of your community are volunteering their time and learning on the job. It’s a learning experience for everyone.

Comment: Congrats everyone!

Comment: Awesome and fantastic! Good work and good luck!

Comment: @pnuts it's survived in its current state for 6 years, I'd say it's fine how it is.

Comment: @pnuts I was just trying trying to say that I can't see any benefit in changing the question's state. No one is likely to vote to delete it and there's no automatic process that's going to remove it either.